# How to control the order of fill and stroke in SVG?

Tags: svg

The order in which fill and stroke are applied makes a difference in the result. With HTML canvas the order can be controlled.

Here is result when fill is applied before stroke:
http://jsfiddle.net/YLk2F/

```
ctx.fillStyle = options.fillColor;
    ctx.fillText(options.text, options.x, options.y);    
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.outlineColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = options.outlineWidth;
    ctx.strokeText(options.text, options.x, options.y);
```

[image]

And when fill is applied after stroke:
http://jsfiddle.net/jsMX9/

```
ctx.strokeStyle = options.outlineColor;
ctx.lineWidth = options.outlineWidth;
ctx.strokeText(options.text, options.x, options.y);
ctx.fillStyle = options.fillColor;
ctx.fillText(options.text, options.x, options.y);
```

[image]

With SVG everything is done via SVG attributes, and it looks like fill is applied before stroke. see e.g.:
http://jsfiddle.net/wYw86/1

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text id="SvgjsText1006" font-family="times new roman" font-size="40pt" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000" transform="translate(100 100)">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1008" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-variant: small-caps; text-decoration: underline;">Hello World!</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

[image]

Is it possible to reverse this order so that fill is applied after stroke in SVG? How?

Comment: Stroke is always applied after fill in SVG. The effect you're seeing may be because you haven't defined your SVG units and the browser is not guessing your intent correctly.

Comment: thanks. you were right. there was a bug in my code (i was using 2 pixels width for the canvas examples and 1 pixel width for svg). i have updated the question with correct code and images.

Comment: do you have any reference to support your claim that stroke is always applied after fill in SVG? it certainly seems that way, but i can't find this in the technical specs for SVG.

Comment: I don’t think you can think of this in terms of “execution order” here actually when it comes to SVG. With your canvas, those are actual _painting_ operations – so of course there a different order of doing the two different things affects the outcome. If fine-tuning the stroke width in your SVG doesn’t give you the desired result – then I think you might achieve it by actually _introducing_ an “order”, by using two elements for the text, apply the stroke to one and the fill to the other – and then position them on top of each other.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#PaintingShapesAndText is the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this with SVG 1.1 (which is what most browsers currently impplement) The upcoming SVG 2 specification will have a [paint-order](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#PaintOrderProperty) property.

Firefox will have paint-order support from version 31 and Chrome should have it soon too if it doesn't already have it.

In the meantime you could always create 2 elements at the same position, fill one and stroke the other which is pretty much what you're doing with canvas now.

Comment: Paint-order is shipped in Chrome 35, see http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/chrome-35-beta-more-developer-control.html.

Comment: SVG 2 implementation seems to be [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408) in Chrome.